# Pass array as route parameters

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table where users can select people. When a person is selected, they are added to an array named `selectedUsers`. When a user clicks the "Select" button they should be taken to the PrintComponent from the ProfileComponent.

I have my routerlink set with:

```
routerLink="['/print/', selectedUsers]"
```

When clicking the "Select" button, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5B'/print/',%20selectedUsers%5D'
```

How can I correctly pass the `selectedUsers` array as a route parameter?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usvlrp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your stackblitz POC is doing `routerLink="['/print/', {users:[selectedUsers}]"` this which is not following what `routerLink` expects.

If you check [this documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) you will see that the `routerLink` expects an array of routes or a single route element  passed in an array.

Take a look at [my stackblitz POC](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jeqbbd) where I have updated `profiles component html` and passed selected user ids as comma separated string to the route.

Comment: Were you looking for `team/11/user/bob;details=true.` this kind of routing structure though? The solution I gave works but it explained a different aspect to be honest!

Comment: I was looking for something like `print/111,113,114` and this gets me very close.

Comment: Alright! this solution does solve the problem then! :)